# Windows 7 visual studio 2013 launching deveoped extension gets "The operation could not be completed-no such interface supported"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vsix

I'm working on a vs 2013 C# Extension project.  Using Windows & and .NET 4.5 The vsix extension, when installed, works fine.  However, something happened a while back, just after adding some changes, and I can no longer start the extension in the debugger.  Selecting the extension project in visual studio and then selecting debug->start new instance causes VS to run through its compilation step and then launch a new version of vs with the extension in place.  However, shortly after the VS black splash rectangle appears a pop up appears giving the message "The operation could not be completed-no such interface supported".  The debugger has launched and is showing the modules being loaded in the "Progress Window".  The last module loaded is ENVDTE80.

Running devenv with /log and copying the log file while the "Operation could not..." message is being displayed shows the last entry to be

```
<entry> <record>1294</record> <time>2016/02/09 16:53:22.122</time> <type>Information</type> <source>VisualStudio</source> <description>Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description> <guid>{80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}</guid>

</entry> </activity>
```

> The guid cited appears many times throughout the activity.log.

I've looked at the odd little error messages from the devenv /LOG log. I've uninstalled the VSIX app from visual studio and then tried debugging > but no joy there.  I've uninstalled visual studio and reinstalled.  I've repaired the .NET installs.  I've repaired the SDK.  Nothing has worked.  There are a few other earlier and simpler versions of the extension and test versions that debug fine.  I'm inclined to think there's some bit of registry entry somewhere that finds a reason not to run this code.

From the devenv activity log I see these error messages:

```
<description>PkgDef configuration error. ApplicationExtensionsFolder omitted from PkgDefSearchPath</description>

The clients rights token could not be found at ....

Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID &apos;Microsoft.Windows.DevelopmentKit.Desktop&apos; is already loaded at > C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\8.0\DESKTOP SDK\...</description>
```

I also have run procmon and captured the events between debug->start separate instance and the presentation of the error message.  Two pids are > traced: one for the original devenv and one for the extension being debugged.  All registry transactions for the debugged extension fall into: SUCCESS, NAME NOT FOUND, NO MORE NAMES FOUND, or BUFFER OVERFLOW.  There is no distinct (to me) single error condition.

The pid associated with the launching devenv, after the last pid entry for the extension being debugged, has several entries ACCESS DENIED associated with HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SQMClient\Windows\CommonDatapoints.

Comparing the devenv.log to the procmon, it is obvious that processing continues after the last entry in the devenv.log for ENVDTE80.  I don't   > seem to be getting anywhere with that correlation.

I've googled this a lot.

The common suggestion for re-registering dlls has not proven to be useful here (yet) (although it seems to have fixed an IE problem which makes it seem to be an attractive approach).

Have also un/re-installed .Net 3.5(.1) with no effect.  Have run sfc /scannow with no effect. Have run NetFxRepairTool with no effect. Have rebuilt the VS extensions experimental hive (12.0-Exp) with no effect. Have un/re-installed vs2013 and the SDK with no effect Have uninstalled other versions of VS and paired SDKs to no effect

Answer (score 0):

I got a little more time to look at this. I uninstalled vs sdk and vs 2013 pro and rebooted.  In reinstalled 2013 pro and vs.  I downloaded the dotnetframework analysis tool are ran it.  I repaired dot net 4.5.1.  Analysis then said to repair dot net 4.6.1 which I did.  Rebooted again.  Tried to run the vs extension in debug and got a different error related to the Ext hive lock file.  This was an improvement from the unknown interface message previously.  Ran the debug again with the devenv log file enabled.  The lock file referenced in the devenv log had a "%&00A%&00D"notation in between the path ending in the /Exp directory name and the /....lock filename.  Edited the profile to remove cr/lf from the end of the /RootSuffix Exp entry and thereafter debug worked.